# issue with $_post, does not know the variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-form-helper

I want to check what is the problem with my $_post['name'] so I wanna check it what is in it, but it says this variable is not define. This problem is a simplified of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054236/simple-php-form-submition-doesnt-save-in-database-and-redirect-to-somewhere-else?noredirect=1#comment44490730_28054236).

messageform_view:

```
<div id="content">
<?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
<?php echo form_open("HomeController/insert_message"); ?>
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

message_model.php:

```
<?php 

class Message_model extends CI_Model {
    public function add_message()
    {

    }
}
?>
```

HomeController:

```
<?php

class HomeController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index () {     
    } 
     public function insert_message()
    {           
        print_r($_POST['name']);
     }
}
?>
```

The Error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: name

Filename: controllers/HomeController.php

Line Number: 22
```

Comment: Check your HTML source code once the page to submit is loaded, I suspect you have no form method set to POST hence your data is coming in as GET.

Comment: @Amir Do you have form tags? (`public function insert_message() { if(!empty($_POST["name"])) print_r($_POST['name']); }`)

Comment: @Prix & @ Rizier123 These are all codes I have, should I define a method for POST!

Comment: @Amir I don't see the HTML of your form so I cannot say whether its set to GET or POST but given your controller can't read your POST I would think its not set to it.

Comment: @Prix my html  template view is messageform_view.php, shall I define a html form  ?

Comment: @Amir and is it empty? what is the content... and also the content of `HomeController/insert_message`! Unhappily my crystal ball is out for maintenance and if you don't show us the relevant parts of code related to the issue it will only make it harder to guess what could be the issue.

Comment: @Amir *shall I define a html form ?*, if not this what else do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: @Prix yes it is empty, I may be wrong but any form you define initially is empty, right?

Comment: .............................. If you don't have the HTML to tell your browser that your form is a POST form it will be defaulted to GET so its only obvious your name field would throw a warning about it being Undefined. I guess you should learn HTML and PHP before you start using a framework.

Comment: You posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/28054236/ and someone marked your present question as an exact duplicate. Why the repost?

Comment: @Darren just an occasional comment on SO, things have been busy lately, anyway, one way to check is right click inspect element on the form, make sure the generated form matches the destination (`action`) you have, i think its default is `POST`, just check it just to be sure. and CI already has that input class. use that one instead, `$this->input->post('whatever_that_name_is')`

Comment: @Ghost, I wrote your code instead of print_r[$_post] and the error is gone, but I get a black page instead of a form with one input name and a submit button

Comment: @Fred-ii- the first question was different with this one, I dont know who flag it as a duplicated, I only mentioned this question is simplified version of previous which is really not, also from the responses  you can see my second question helped me alot

Comment: @Amir well, i think thats bound to happen since `insert_message()`'s intent is just to insert form input, not the actual form page. so it is blank. just use your model methods and continue on your active record insertion. insert then redirect to form page.

Comment: Ok, will leave it at that then Amir.

Answer (score 0):

remove the below code from the view

```
<?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
```

in application/config/autoload.php add below code

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

in controller to check value of form

```
print_r($this->input->post());die;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in view part : you will get the answer

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url('HomeController/insert_message'); ?>" method="post">
    <p>
     <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
    </form>
```

in controller get the name field as

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
```